# Comparing value enclosed in RefCell<T>

Tags: rust, interior-mutability

I have a structure with a field defined as follows:

```
log_str: RefCell<String>
```

I performed various calls to `borrow_mut()` to call `push_str(.)` on the field. At the end, I'm assessing its value using:

```
assert_eq!(os.log_str.borrow(), "<expected value>");
```

Nonetheless, the line of the assert raises a compile-time error with the message:

> error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `std::cell::Ref<'_, std::string::String>`

I understand why the error is happening, since the compiler even hints:

> an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `std::cell::Ref<'_, std::string::String>`

My question is: how should I compare the value enclosed in a `RefCell<T>` (typically in this case, comparing the enclosed string with an expected value).

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to de-reference the `borrow`ed value:

```rust
assert_eq!(*os.log_str.borrow(), "<expected value>");
```

Comment: Alright! `Ref<.>` can effectively be dereferenced (I guess thanks to the implementation of `Deref` trait). Thanks!